# "Find my iPhone" Google Maps tiling texture

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am really impressed by the way Apple has [styled the Google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZug9.png) in their "Find my iPhone" section on iCloud. They have added a really subtle paper texture and removed all company names and labels.

What I would love to know is how they accomplished this. I can't find any documentation in the [Google Maps V3 API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) on tileable overlays, nor can I find it in iCloud's (minified) JS source.

All clues are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out! For those searching:

```
/* Basic Google map options */
var options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.131802, 5.289917),
    zoom: 12
}

/* Render the map */
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

/* Create a custom map type */
var texturedMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(tileCoord, zoom, ownerDocument)
    {
        /* Return the same tile for every coord and zoom level */
        return '/assets/img/bg-map-tile.png';
    },
    isPng: true,                    
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
});

/* Add a new layer between the map and the markers and render tiles here */
map.overlayMapTypes.push(null);
map.overlayMapTypes.setAt(0, texturedMapType);
```

As for the removal of street, POI and other labels, see [Creating a StyledMapType](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html#creating_a_styledmaptype). That's all.

See the result here: http://www.ufomeldpunt.nl/kaart#latest

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by tileable overlays in this context. However, Google Maps API V3 does allow for styling the map:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html

And you can do a Ground Overlay:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#GroundOverlays